# SQL Oracle IN operator behavior

Tags: sql, oracle

I use Oracle and I can't explain this behavior :

```
SELECT DUMMY 
FROM   DUAL 
WHERE  DUMMY IN (SELECT DUMMY FROM z_sites);
```

Returns

```
DUMMY
-----
X
```

And this :

```
SELECT DUMMY FROM z_sites;
```

Returns

> ORA-00904: "DUMMY" : identificateur non valide
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

So on my first query, the subquery is false, but the query still excutes itself ?!

Comment: The subquery's DUMMY refers to the main query DUAL column. I.e. `... WHERE  DUMMY IN (SELECT DUAL.DUMMY FROM z_sites);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is all about scope:

```
SELECT DUMMY 
FROM   DUAL 
WHERE  DUMMY IN (SELECT DUMMY FROM z_sites);
```

is same as:

```
SELECT DUMMY 
FROM   DUAL 
WHERE  DUMMY IN (SELECT DUAL.DUMMY FROM z_sites);
```

Whereas:

```
SELECT DUMMY FROM z_sites;
-- there is no dummy column in z_sites table
```

---

To make thing more interesting you could check what will happen if z_sites contains dummy column:

```
CREATE TABLE z_sites(dummy VARCHAR2(100));
INSERT INTO z_sites(dummy) VALUES('Y');

SELECT DUMMY 
FROM   DUAL 
WHERE  DUMMY IN (SELECT DUMMY FROM z_sites);
-- 0 rows selected
<=>
SELECT DUMMY 
FROM   DUAL 
WHERE  DUMMY IN (SELECT z_sites.DUMMY FROM z_sites);
-- 0 rows selected

SELECT DUMMY 
FROM   DUAL 
WHERE  DUMMY IN (SELECT DUAL.DUMMY FROM z_sites);

DUMMY
-----
X
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f522f1318436c4f07b63fd608a2a11b3)**

Summing up: **always prefix your columns in subquery to avoid confusion.**